# Date calculation - progressbar showing timeleft

Tags: java, date

i want to make a simple progressbar showing me how much time some process takes. At the moment of creation of it I have only actual percentage (as int) and time that is left(as String formatted HH:mm:ss). I want it to update every second and show me the actual state of process. I've tried everything and it doesn't work. Current version looks like this - tell me please what I'm doing wrong...

```
int initialProgress = 35; // %
// time to finish process
Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse("07:07:07"); 
Date now = new Date();
long totalDuration = (long) (((double)(endDate.getTimeInMillis() 
              - now.getTimeInMillis()) * 100.0 / (double)initialProgress);
```

and then every second I repeat:

```
now = new Date();
int currentProgress = (totalDuration - endDate.getTimeInMillis()   
              + now.getTimeInMillis())/totalDuration;
```

It simply is not working. Total duration is even something strange...

Comment: Please define "it simply is not working." Tell us the details, anything that will help us understand your problem.

Comment: You're parsing a duration (your string) to a date. This is obviously wrong.

Comment: 'SimpleDataFormatter' is there any class remain with this name.

Comment: @MasudCSECUET I think he meant `SimpleDurationFormatter` :)

Comment: sorry, I ment http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html And by saying it doesn't work I want to say that it counts progress, but it has nothing in common with the actual values. I get 100% when really there's for example 75%. And of course this is simplified code. I don't parse String but a variable containing string.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you have a time remaining `String` and you want to parse it to percentage of work done.

The first thing you need, obviously, is the total expected time. Lets assume that this is also a `String`.

First write a method for parsing your `HH:mm:ss` `String` to a `long` representing time remaining in seconds.

```
public long parseToSeconds(final String duration) throws ParseException {
    final MessageFormat durationFormat = new MessageFormat("{0,number,#}:{1,number,#}:{2,number,#}");
    final Object[] parsedTimeRemaining = durationFormat.parse(duration);
    final long totalDuration = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds((Long) parsedTimeRemaining[0])
            + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds((Long) parsedTimeRemaining[1])
            + (Long) parsedTimeRemaining[2];
    return totalDuration;
}
```

What we do here is use a `MessageFormat` to parse your `String` into an array of `Object`. As we have told the `MessageFormat` that these are numbers, it will automagically convert (or try to convert, hence the exception) to `Long`.

Once we have those numbers we scale them all to seconds using the (very useful) `TimeUnit` class.

A couple of quick tests to ensure we're on the right track:

```
System.out.println(parseToSeconds("00:00:01"));
System.out.println(parseToSeconds("00:01:00"));
System.out.println(parseToSeconds("01:00:00"));
System.out.println(parseToSeconds("01:01:01"));
```

Output:

> 1
>   60
>   3600
>   3661

Looks good.

Lets assume that right as the start of the process we get a time remaining, for simplicity, of "04:04:04", this gives `14644`. Now we just need to store that and calculate the percentage against any new duration `String`. This should do the trick:

```
public int asPercentage(final long totalTime, final long remaining) {
    final double percentage = remaining / ((double) totalTime);
    return (int) (percentage * 100);
}
```

Note the fact that I cast (seemingly pointlessly) one of the items to a `double`. This is because in Java any operation on an integral type always returns another  integral type. Casting to a `double` forces it to return a `double`.

Lets do a quick check again:

```
final long totalDuration = 14644;
System.out.println(asPercentage(totalDuration, parseToSeconds("03:03:03")));
System.out.println(asPercentage(totalDuration, parseToSeconds("02:02:02")));
System.out.println(asPercentage(totalDuration, parseToSeconds("01:01:01")));
```

Output:

> 75
>   50
>   25

Looks good, that is the time remaining as a percentage of the total. Maybe to quite what we want for a progress bar. Lets invert it:

```
public static int asPercentage(final long totalTime, final long remaining) {
    final double percentage = remaining / ((double) totalTime);
    return 100 - (int) (percentage * 100);
}
```

Output:

> 25
>   50
>   75

Ah-ha. Much better.

Comment: You didn't read carefully my post. I wrote that I have ONLY time left and current percentage. Also what for do I need my own converters if I can simply use SimpleDateFormat.parse. The whole problem is in counting total duration.

Comment: You need your own formatters because time left is a duration, not a time. So parsing "07:07:07" to a time doesn't help you; you need to parse it to a number of seconds. This is why you are getting odd results; i.e. you parse the time remaining to a time and the check if it's later than now - so at 8:00 your task will _always_ be 100% done. As for the rest, I don't understand the question then; please edit your question to be more clear.